# SQL full text index missing result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 3 records in my table:

> - This is a test record 1
> - This is a test record 2
> - This is a test record 3

Now i'm trying to using Contains or FreeText function to search the result that contain the text 'This'.

```
Select * from tblData where Freetext(DataText, 'This')
Select * from tblData where Contains(DataText, 'This')
```

Both of them show 0 result.

But if i try to search another word, it working normally:

```
Select * from tblData where Freetext(DataText, 'test')
Select * from tblData where Contains(DataText, 'test')
```

How do i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check stoplist words of your fulltext by following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fulltext_stopwords
```

You can also disable stoplist of your fulltext index by following query:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON yourtable SET STOPLIST OFF
```